# Linking c++ files

Tags: c++, c, linker

I have A header file which contains declaration of a function, let's call it A.h, i have implementation of this function in file A1.cpp. Now A1.cpp has other file includes. Not all included files in A1.cpp are available (3rd party issue). Now my question is , Is it possible to make function call from a file let's say main.cpp, dynamically linking to A1.cpp(without compiling A1.cpp) as i have some files from 3rd party not available ?

My guess is no, because unless i have included files available i can't get object file of A1.cpp and hence i can't call function. However correct me if i am wrong , a compiled file of A1.cpp i.e A1.o can still be used as i can link to it and hence make function call without dependency on other include files(which i don't have?)

Go easy on me , i'm not a C++ guy :-) !! Any help or insight in this matter is appreciated !! Oh btw i have started to use ndk for android, n hence the trouble :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the object file (`A.o`) why can't you just link it in your binary ?

```
g++ -o main main.o A.o
```

Comment: How will linking to A.o which only contains function declaration will ever get the function definition defined in A1.cpp ? Is it even possible, just wondering ...I guess Not as far as i can think ..

Comment: At the time `A.o` was compiled, there were all necessary source files available. So, you get the third-party-closed stuff as precompiled binary blob. That's sufficient for linking to. And the interface you have available as cleartext `A.h`. Should work. It's common to get commercial libraries in this form (static libraries).
It might well be that you also need other binary blobs `blahblah.o` for satisfying dependencies of `A.o`, though.

Comment: Hmm.. this actually makes sense, but then if blahblah.h had other dependencies in it as other included files, i would need all other dependent binary blobs, so i guess answer i was looking for is get binary blobs of all dependencies (if at all) and then i can be happy man or else i'm a dead duck :-)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question right then the answer is no, not when the target is just a cpp file. 
  The only ways to link to something else without compiling it would be to put it in a dll or a precompiled library (.lib in windows). If the third part stuff is in a .lib or a dll then you should be in luck, you just need the header file and then tell your compiler to link the static or dynamic library.
  Let me know if that made sense, if not I can clarify given more information about your set up and what you're trying to link.

Comment: Ok consider this 
File A.h
void hello();

File A1.cpp
#include "blahblah.cpp"    // i dont have blahblah.cpp
#include "A.h"

void hello(){
//something here
}

file main.cpp

#include "A.h"

void main(){

hello();
}

Now can i compile main, as i have A.h and A1.cpp, so i included A.h in main, i could have included A1.cpp in main as well, but problem is i dont have blahblah.h available. So i was trying to work around A1.cpp by linking to it dynamically, but my guess is it's not possible ( i see why it's not possible), so having A1.o is the only remedy in case i can't get dependencies in A1.cpp ?